# Filter array inside array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the array as below

```
test_list = [
{ 
    id: 1,
    test_name: 'Test 1',
    members: [
        {
            user_id: 3
        },
        {
            user_id: 4
        }
    ],
},
{ 
    id: 2,
    test_name: 'Test 2',
    members: [
        {
           user_id: 4
        },
        {
            user_id: 5
        },
    ],
},
{ 
    id: 3,
    test_name: 'Test 2',
    members: [
        {
            user_id: 8
        },  
        {
            user_id: 10
        },
    ],
}
]
```

I want to filter the test for specific user_id, example if user_id = 4 I would like to have this result

```
{ 
    id: 1,
    ...
},
{ 
    id: 2,
    ...
},
```

I have tried with this but it only return the member

```
test_list.filter(function(item) {
      item.members.filter(function(member) {
        if(member.user_id === 4) {
          return item;
        }
      });
    })
```

Would anyone please help me in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `.some` of the objects in the `members` array have the `user_id` you're looking for:

```js
test_list = [{
    id: 1,
    test_name: 'Test 1',
    members: [{
        user_id: 3
      },
      {
        user_id: 4
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    test_name: 'Test 2',
    members: [{
        user_id: 4
      },
      {
        user_id: 5
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    test_name: 'Test 2',
    members: [{
      user_id: 8
    }]
  }
];

const filtered = test_list.filter(
  ({ members }) => members.some(
    ({ user_id }) => user_id === 4
  )
);
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method of array to achieve required result.

Please check below working code snippet:

```js
const arr = [{"id":1,"test_name":"Test 1","members":[{"user_id":3},{"user_id":4}]},{"id":2,"test_name":"Test 2","members":[{"user_id":4},{"user_id":5}]},{"id":3,"test_name":"Test 2","members":[{"user_id":8}]}];

const data = arr.reduce((r,{ members,...rest }) => {
  let rec = members.filter(o => o.user_id === 4)
  if(rec.length){
    rest.members = rec;
    r.push(rest);
  }
  return r;
},[]);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works.

````
  var members = item.members;
  var filterById =members.filter((item1)=>{
    return (item1.user_id===4)
  });
  return filterById.length > 0;
});
console.log(test_List_by_id)```
````